# Opening Text Files in Python 2.78 with Windows PowerShell

Tags: file, python-2.7, powershell

I have a txt file named sample.txt, and I want to open it via the Windows Powershell in Python. I want the contents of the text file to be opened and displayed within the shell. So I go to the folder that the txt file is located in, and I ran python in the shell. However, I'm not sure where to go from here. When I do

```
open(sample.txt)
```

or

```
sample.txt.read()
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'ex15_sample' is not defined
```

I've tried Googling, but I can't find anything.

Edit: It wasn't working because I didn't include double quotes for the file name and it thought I was referring to a variable named sample.

Comment: In Python you can do something like `open("sample.txt").read()`, but what does this have to do with Powershell?

Comment: I just wanted to be able to execute single commands within the shell. I just tried your command, and it seems I was just missing the quotes before and after the file name. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Basically the variable needs to be defined.

You have to write the exact code on the python shell as you wrote on your ex15.py file to open the text file, like this:

```
txt = open('ex15_sample.txt')

txt.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the exact code on the python shell as you wrote on your `ex15.py` file to open the text file. Like this:

```
txt = open('ex15_sample.txt')
txt.read()
```